# Installation of the Catalyst drivers in a ATI / Intel hybrid laptop

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics, intel

I have installed the Catalyst drivers in my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit but they don't seem to be working.

`lspci -nn | grep VGA` returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Madison [AMD Radeon HD 5000M Series] [1002:68c1]
```

It seems I have 2 cards in my system, on Intel and one ATI, I want to work with the ATI but the drivers don't seem to be working. What can I do?

> Related question:
>   [How to re-configure graphics from Intel integrated to Intel / ATI switchable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189540/how-to-re-configure-graphics-from-intel-integrated-to-intel-ati-switchable)
>   (describes the only switching option (manual) available to us - users of legacy graphics)

Comment: digitare `fglrxinfo` nel terminale e invia la tua uscita. dispiace per il cattivo italiano

Comment: Ciao, penso di una incompatibilita' del ATI 64bit driver. Se sia possibile, potresti provare Ubuntu 32bit.

Comment: This site uses English as it's main language and people are expected to ask and comment in English. Also, please do not use the _Answer_ button to add more information to your question, you can edit it instead.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Nvidia, but ATI, the duplicated is invalid as such.

Comment: @Braiam however this question is also past End Of Life, as the question is about 11.10.  The question would be closed anyways...

Comment: @ThomasW. when it was asked was on-topic, the close reason is incorrect anyways

Answer (score 2):

(*Taken from the [`ATI wiki`](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Intel.2FATI_Hybrids) site*):

> Intel/ATI Hybrids
>
> Use of Catalyst on older systems (those with a mux) is no longer supported. I have one report of switching success with Catalyst 11-6, but ATI has now disabled switching in Catalyst, even if it worked fine with older Catalyst versions. X will refuse to start and you will find this message in your Xorg log:
>
> ```
> (WW) PowerXpress feature is not supported on A+I Mux platform. Please uninstall fglrx driver.
>  (EE) No devices detected.
> ```

Your hybrid solution of Intel/ATI cards in your system is not supported by the Catalyst drivers. Switching was once possible but has been disabled  later on by AMD.

Unless you can disable the Intel card in your BIOS and run only with the ATI graphics there is no way you can install the AMD drivers for your card. You are stuck running the Intel graphics card by default.

***You will not be able to install Catalyst drivers in this situation and you can run Ubuntu with your Intel graphics card.***