# How to increase resolution in ubuntu 15.10? using xrandr and updating nvidia drivers didn't work

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10, display-resolution

Friends,

I have spent 2 days already trying to get ubuntu work on my laptop. I am getting various problems with graphics. Upon installing from USB I cannot immediately enter due to **"low-graphics mode" problem**. I can **sidestep it by adding nomodeset** to the booting options, but the problems don't end there.

Now I am able to login, but the **resolution is terrible**. Typing `xrandr` in the console yields:
`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768`

I tried to follow [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res) in order to **use xrandr to add a new resolution mode**. In vain.

`xrandr --newmode VGA1 "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hsync'`

In another topic it has been suggested that I should **get proper graphic card divers**. When **I installed nvidia drivers**, I wasn't
able to even enter the login screen, it just went black immediately. I tried to purge and reinstall nvidia drivers but it did not help. Welp, I **reinstalled ubuntu** from my USB. Then I **tried bumblebee**, which I read were good nvidia drivers. After rebooting **nothing happened**, still low resolution with xrandr manipulations yielding nothing.

At this point I am very confused and feel rather deflated. The solution probably is somewhere there, I went through countless threads but just can't quite get it. If there is **any information** that you might find useful to solve it, **I will be happy to provide it**.

**Computer Specs:**
Model: Asus N551JM
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem accidentally...
For future generations, here is the solution:
After installing the bumblebee pack as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04) I rebooted ubuntu and forgot to boot it with "nomodeset". Somehow, now it works without it and everything is good ;)