# Cannot change my screen resolution on IBM server

Tags: server, ibm

When changing the screen size with the command `xrandr`, terminal always returns:

```
xrandr: Failed to get the measure gamma to standard output
```

I'm using this [blog](https://whyubuntu.blogspot.com/) as reference to change resolution.

[image: message in my terminal]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Rather than snapshotting of terminal output, please copy the output to your question, then use `code` format on it.

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo -s` actually will grant you root privilege, so there's no need `sudo` anymore to register new mode. Besides, you do not need `sudo` with xrandr.

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664 720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00
```

Replace `VGA-0` with your connected device, run `xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"` to get your paired device.

It also appear that the gamma error is related to graphic driver problem, you might want to take a look at following thread:

- [Failed to get size of gamma for output](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=202637)
- [Failed to get size of gamma for output default when trying to add new screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res)
- [Screen resolution issues after upgrade, xrandr ?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141577)