# How can I add a new screen resolution to an old laptop?

Tags: laptop, display-resolution, 17.10

I have an old laptop (Esprimo Mobile). I am new to Ubuntu. I ran `xrandr -q` and the only option available is 640 x 480

```
$ xrandr -q 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480 default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm 
640x480 73.00* 
1240x800_60.00 (0x288) 80.750MHz -HSync +VSync
 h: width 1240 start 1304 end 1432 total 1624 skew 0 clock 49.72KHz 
v: height 800 start 803 end 813 total 831 clock 59.84Hz –
```

This makes my windows on screen way too big. How can I fix them?

EDIT: Since posting I have managed to create a new screen resolution option. When I applied the 1240 x 800 resolution it made things worse, all the windows became even wider and the top bar stretched out so I couldn't see the far right corner. I switched back from the 1240x800 (3:2) to the 640 x 480 but i am back where I started. What do I need to change?

Comment: followed that but issue with failed to find gamma output?

Comment: David, please [edit] your question and add the exact steps that you've performed and the error message you've received.

Comment: What is the exact model of the laptop. We should find the native resolution and refresh rate of its monitor.

Comment: Fujitsu Esprimo Mobile V5335

Comment: I think its resolution is 1280x800. And you cold try to generate modes with 59, 60 Hz (`cvt 1280 800 59`, `cvt 1280 800 60`).

Comment: How do I  generate a mode?

Comment: David, which Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Sorry, was at work.
O/S Ubuntu 17.10 artful (x86-64)
Linux kernel 4.13.0-16 generic
Graphics card Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adaptor

Comment: I think the approach from my suggestions shall work within [Ubuntu on Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10). **For Ubuntu on Wayland you could try this approach: [Wayland how to set a custom resolution](https://askubuntu.com/a/973582/566421)**

Comment: You might want to use 16.04 if you have the SIS video. It is being obsoleted as it has an insecure API. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371684

Answer (score 3):

**Please note the following approach shall work within [Ubuntu on Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10). For Ubuntu on Wayland you could try this approach: [Wayland how to set a custom resolution](https://askubuntu.com/a/973582/566421).**

---

I did a little research and I think the native resolution of Esprimo Mobile V5335 is 1280x800. I think the refresh rate should be 59 or 60 Hz, but maybe I'm wrong.

About the refresh rate in `man cvt` is written:

```
refresh - Provide a vertical refresh rate in Hz.   
          The CVT standard prefers either 50.0, 60.0, 75.0 or 85.0Hz.   
          The default is 60.0Hz.
```

**How to calculate, generate and set new mode using `cvt` and `xrandr`**

- *In the examples below I use resolution 1280x800@60Hz.*

**1.** Use the command `cvt` to calculate the new modeline:

```
$ cvt 1280 800 60

# 1280x800 59.81 Hz (CVT 1.02MA) hsync: 49.70 kHz; pclk: 83.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
```

**2.** Use `xrandr` to create the new mode:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
```

- *Please note `"1280x800_60.00"` is the name of the mode. If you wish you could change it as desired, for example `"1280x800_custom_1"`.*

**3.** Use `xrandr` to find your [output name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res). Just execute `xrandr` without any arguments. The output name should be VGA1, DP1, HDMI1, HDMI-1, LVDS1, LVDS-1, etc. For our example, let's assume the output name is `LVDS-1`.

**4.** Use `xrandr` to add the new mode to the list of modes of your output:

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 1280x800_60.00
```

**5.** Activate the new mode:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1280x800_60.00
```

- *In the worst case, if the screen image disappears, just power off and power on the computer.*

**6.** When you find the right mode, you can make the changes permanent with one of the methods described here: [Adding newmode with Xrandr - "800x480_60.00"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890231/adding-newmode-with-xrandr-800x480-60-00).