# There are other ways to launch a script on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, scripts

I already checked several tutorials, but I can't run my script when starting the operating system. I already put the file in /etc/init.d , /boot, /bin, /urs/bin . I think I already put it in every possible place. here's my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting command to put resolution on 1920x1080"
echo "Password_of_sudo" | sudo -S xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync && 
sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00 && 
sudo xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
echo "Finished.
```

**Note**: runs within a VM. And it works when starts manually, the problem is that i don't want to run manually i want it to start when the system loads.

Comment: Here are another two possible answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/890253/566421 and https://askubuntu.com/a/975552/566421

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Create a `/etc/systemd/system/xrandr.service` file (you could specify the service name you like) using:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/system/xrandr.service
  ```
- Put the next inside of it:

  ```
  [Unit]
  After=multi-user.target

  [Service]
  User=your_user
  ExecStart=/home/your_user/scripts/xrandr.sh

  [Install]
  WantedBy=default.target
  ```
- Place your script into `/home/your_user/scripts` folder or specify path to your script.
- `sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/xrandr.service`
- `sudo systemctl enable xrandr.service`
- Check if it is working by `sudo systemctl start xrandr.service`

Also, you could modify your file the next way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting command to put resolution on 1920x1080" | logger
export DISPLAY=:0 && xhost + local
echo "Password_of_sudo" | sudo -S xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync && 
sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00 && 
sudo xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
echo "Finished." | logger
```

But it is better do not use `sudo` or admin privileges if commands do not require it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting command to put resolution on 1920x1080" | logger
export DISPLAY=:0 
xrandr --newmode "1920_new_name" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync && 
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00 && 
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
echo "Finished." | logger
```

Check your display by `echo $DISPLAY`, then if you have not `:0`, then change it in your script.

To see what is wrong with your script, you could use the next command for monitoring in terminal:

```
$ journalct -f
```

Comment: I would suggest not to do `sudo` with plain text password but to run the script as a user with sufficient privileges to begin with.

Comment: thank you very much it worked right. I will remove this part of the sudo command

Answer (score 2):

As this is a command meant to be run as root at system start, you could add it as a cron job launched by root (I used *higor* as your user, *vm* as your system name) with the following:

```
higor@vm$ sudo su -                       #this changes to root temporarily
[sudo] password for higor:                #enter your password
root@vm# cp /home/higor/script.sh /root   #copy the script to /root home
root@vm# chown root:root script.sh        #make the script property of root
root@vm# chmod u+x script.sh              #make the script executable
root@vm# VISUAL=nano crontab -e           #uses nano to edit crontab config of root
```

then add the following line:

```
@reboot /root/script.sh >/root/script.sh.log 2>&1
```

Save the file, and return to user *higor* with the command `exit`.

This line will be processed each system restart as root (you could learn more about cron configuration using the command `man 5 crontab`), and write any messages or errors to the file `/root/script.sh.log`. As this script already runs as root, doesn't need launching commands inside it with `sudo`; simply write the commands themselves.

Comment: thank you very much, I will do this