# Stuck at 640x480 - Run Nouveau and nVidia graphic drivers side-by-side?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, nouveau, gpu-driver

I have recently installed a **nVidia Tesla K80 graphics accelerator** into an existing dual-socket workstation running **Ubuntu 20.04** with a low-energy consumption **nVidia Quadro NVS315**. After updating the **nVidia drivers** (from legacy 390 that were needed for the Quadro to 450 in order to support CUDA on the K80), the now unsupported Quadro is stuck at a **resolution of 640x480**, leaving me unable to use [xrandr](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) to introduce additional custom resolutions. I have already [asked the friendly folks at nVidia](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/driver-issue-with-gpu-and-hwa-in-ubuntu-stuck-at-low-resolution/142137) and they have confirmed that it is indeed a driver issue (as the Quadro is a legacy GPU by now) and that it is not possible to use two different nVidia drivers in parallel.

I have also tried to use **Nouveau** but I was unable to turn it on only for the Quadro in *"Software & Updates/Additional Drivers"*, all the entries apart from *"Continue using a manually installed driver"* are greyed out for the Quadro if the nVidia-proprietary 450 driver is activated for the Tesla. If I switch both devices to Nouveau I have the full resolution but I can't run code on the Tesla.

Furthermore I have tried to change the [Grub framebuffer resolution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution) [as proposed in this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167437/1013976) but then every graphic interface loads very slowly like a scan-line that takes almost a second per refresh.

As it is close to impossible to code on 640x480, I would like to ask if there is a way to **force** the Quadro running on the manually installed drivers to use a **higher resolution** or if I can force Ubuntu to **use Nouveau only for the Quadro**, while using the 450 drivers for the Tesla. Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks for taking your time. :)

Comment: @Nmath Hey nmath, sadly it is a dual Xeon machine without onboard graphics. Yeah, I have only noticed now that Nouveau mentions on their official page that it isn't compatible with official Nvidia graphic drivers either, so I can't run it parallel to the Tesla nVidia driver as well... The tesla is a computing card, so has no graphic output. I heard there exist ways to output over the mainboard (so potentially also over the NVS 315) but I think this will reduce the computational power of the Tesla.

Comment: I ended [cranking up the **Grub2 frame buffer resolution**](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/driver-issue-with-gpu-and-hwa-in-ubuntu-stuck-at-low-resolution/142137/4?u=rootofpi) to the highest acceptable rate where it would not start lagging 1024x768, so I can use the nVidia driver while working with CUDA. For normal desktop use I will turn on the Nouveau driver in "Software & Updates/Additional Drivers" and can get the full resolution on the NVS 315 but without being able to use CUDA. In any case thanks for your feedback and have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [two possible solutions](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/driver-issue-with-gpu-and-hwa-in-ubuntu-stuck-at-low-resolution/142137) that both worked for me

- [**Increase the GRUB frame buffer resolution**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution): For me the resolution in this case was limited to  1024×768 - with [higher resolutions](https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/grub-vga-modes.html) it would start lagging.
- **Buy a newer generation low-power graphics card** (I ended up with a Nvidia Quadro P620 to accompany my Nvidia Tesla K80) that is compatible with the same version of the regular Nvidia graphics driver (e.g. [**450.51**.05 Data center driver](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/162034/en-uk) -> supported products -> Nvidia Tesla K80 and [**450.51** Display driver](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/160555/en-us) -> supported products -> Nvidia Quadro P620)