# Resolution was reset after upgrade, Xrandr failed to get size of gamma for output default

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm on *Ubuntu 20.04* and after an upgrade, my resolution was reset on reboot.
I went from a **1920x1080** resolution to a **800x600**.

I normally use **arandr** to adjust my resolution, but now I only have the 800x600 option.
My output was named `VGA` or something similar. Now it's called `default`.

When I enter the command `xrandr -q`, I got this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       75.00*
```

Can someone help me to fix this urgently, please ?
This is almost impossible to work like this.

By the way, I already tried these:
[Failed to get size of gamma for output default when trying to add new screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res)
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391669/xrandr-displaying-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default without any success.

When I enter this `lspci | grep VGA`, I got this output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
```

I don't really know if this is important, but I saw people giving their GPU specs on several posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the solution here:
https://www.fosslinux.com/41008/install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-command-line-and-gui-ways.htm

Basically, the upgrade somehow uninstalled my Nvidia drivers.

I just reinstall them with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` before rebooting.

Comment: this worked like a charm. For reference, I am using Ubuntu 20 on a DELL 49'

Comment: @Bravo2bad, you are my hero.  I've been struggling trying to figure out why my temp USB install of Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 LTS displayed both monitors, but when permanently installed to hard drive, only one monitor was displayed.  This reinstall command worked just great.

Comment: as of 22.04 it is `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 22.04 - I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` which basically installed nvidia drivers only and it worked. Just go to `additional drivers` > you can find `nvidia corporation` > continue using a manually installed driver(in the bulleted list below it).