# xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default on UBUNTU 22.04

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with

```
$ lspci | grep VG
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
```

Today the resolution of the display was forced to 1024x728 (refresh rate 76 Hz) with no options. I am getting the error `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`, so I tried the solutions of these posts [(1)](https://davidtsadler.com/posts/linux/2021-06-05/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default/), [(2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res), [(3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278290/resolution-was-reset-after-upgrade-xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-outpu). But nothing has changed.

How can I force a resolution of 1920 x 1080? Or let the system recognize the display automatically as before?

Thank you

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers? If so, how?

Comment: I did not: they were already there from the installation of U. 22.04 given that the display was recognized and recognized with the right definition. I have installed `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` though. The problem happen suddenly yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`