# Ubuntu 20.04.3 - Display resolution stuck at 640x480 after fresh install

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution

**The Problem**

So, this was my first time doing this. I prepared the bootable pendrive, followed the steps of installation and saw everything working fine using the preview feature, with the correct resolution: 1920x1080. The problem is: after i properly installed Ubuntu and rebooted my PC, the screen resolution dropped to 640x480 and the options to change that back are not available in the configs.

I’ve attempted finding a solution on my own, but everything I tried to do didn’t work and/or made things worse, to the point where it would not boot and I had to reinstall it. I decided, then, to look for help and ask a question here.

Thanks in advance!

---

**More information**

- Motherboard: Gigabyte Ga-78lmt-s2 Am3 Am3+ Fx 4100-Fx 8370e
- Graphic card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550 Ti

Running `xrandr` returns:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

Running `inxi -G` returns:

```
Graphics: 
  Device-1: NVIDIA GF116 [Geforce GTX 550 Ti] driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev,nouveau
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 640x480~73Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3
```

---

**Things i've tried**

Solutions from https://snawarhussain.com/blog/ubuntu/linux/troubleshoot/ubuntu-20.04-resolution-stuck-at-1280-x-720/ alongside with [Failed to get size of gamma for output default when trying to add new screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res).

`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` still haunts.

- **Edit_1**:
  https://davidtsadler.com/posts/linux/2021-06-05/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default/ also couldn't solve it for me. It does not seem to be what is causing my problem, since my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is already set to `"quiet splash"` from beggining.

Comment: Have you selected the option to install additional drivers? If not you can do it now in Additional Drivers.

Comment: what graphics driver are you using? and what options do you get when searching for additional drivers?

Comment: are you on a hybrid graphic configuration?

Comment: @ChanganAuto, i don't think i have.

Comment: @trondhansen I'm not sure. When i open "Additional Drivers", i see my graphic card described there: "NVIDIA CORPORATION: GF116 [Geforce GTX 550 Ti]". Just below it, i see: "This device is using a manually-installed driver." Then, a lot of options, but i can't choose any of them, just the one that it is already selected: "Continue using a manually installed driver".

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher Hmm, i use just one GPU, the one i mentioned, so i think not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i **found a solution** to this problem of mine!

**Here:** https://www.fosslinux.com/41008/install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-command-line-and-gui-ways.htm

I just followed the tutorial and installed the nvidia-driver-390 by cmd, since i was not able to change it in "Additional Drivers". Once i rebooted the system, it started in 1920x1080 and many others are now available at display settings.

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

How did I solve the problem in Sony E series VPCEH3AEN with latest kernel version

1. ubuntu-drivers devices
   this command listed the nvidia driver. There I could see 390 driver installation option.
2. sudo apt-get install nvidia-390-somthing

If you are not able to get to the graphical mode after reboot. Just go to recovery mode and then enable networking and then go to the command line and run above command.