# Ubuntu won't boot! MTD DEVICE MUST BE SUPPLIED

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I edited a .conf file because I wanted to allow multiple screens on Nvidia graphics card. I then restarted my laptop (I have dual boot) and have this problem:

[recovering journal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZOqf.jpg)

It goes completely blank afterwards.

[better quality picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHhAo.jpg)

Comment: Which file did you edit?  The MTD message is just a warning, many are seeing it, but that is not your problem.

Comment: ```/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf``` i edited this file.. i deleted it with ubuntu recovery boot in root mode, but it's still showing the error

Comment: Check your /var/log/Xorg.0.log (and Xorg.1.log) file(s).  Looks like a video problem, forget the mtd message.  I've not needed an xorg.conf file for multiple monitors for years.  Which Nvidia driver are you using, and what Nvidia hardware. Assuming the 5.15.0... kernel. Is secure boot off? Search this site for "blank screen at login"  for similar problems.

Comment: @ubfan1  thanks - i'll look into it  i'm not fully sure, but I think i installed a dummy video driver like so ```sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy``` however I did uninstall it, as well as I deleted all files associated with it.. and nothing

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat random solution that worked for me  (I don't know how though):

[Failed to get size of gamma for output default when trying to add new screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441040/failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-when-trying-to-add-new-screen-res/1167437#1167437)

I had to enter recovery mode, so I could change the grub resolution (GRUB_GFXMODE) to the default one for my video card. After that, the blank screen goes away, replaced by a normal boot process.