# Using my AMD Radeon™ HD 8750M Graphics in 13.04

Tags: drivers, switchable-graphics

I have been trying to get my dedicated graphics (AMD Radeon™ HD 8750M Graphics) working on my Samsung series 5 laptop. It just shows Intel® Ivybridge Mobile in the system details and gaming performance is much worse on the integrated card. Both fglrx and fglrx-updates broke unity completely. I don't mind using open source AMD drivers as long as I can activate my dedicated card (and preferably be able to switch to it only when gaming either manually or automatically). How can I activate my dedicated graphics?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/121947/169736

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest BETA drivers from the AMD website. Here's a [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64)

Extract the file somewhere in your Home folder and make the file executable:

```
chmod +x amd_xxxxx.run
```

Then:

```
sudo ./amd_xxxxx.run
```

Install the drivers following an automatic setup. After the installation is complete make sure you run this command before restarting:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Restart you laptop and the ATI Catalyst drivers should be installed and working.

Remember that these are BETA drivers so you may encounter some issues. For more information about the drivers read [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx)

Comment: If there are any dependencies missing, check [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) out for information of how to install ATI hybrid drivers. P.S. The STEP 2 of this guide make my graphics worse, in my opinion, that could be because it's a guide for an old version of the drivers.

Comment: Hello, doing this has left with with a terminal again. (No graphics). I installed latest stable on 13.10 because they were newer than beta. did what you and other guide said and restarted. Thrown into a terminal. It said there was an error during install followed by a message saying the install had succeeded. So I went on, did the config and rebooted :/.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this AMD page might help:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Perhaps you might be able to disable the integrated graphics in the BIOS. It might avoid confusion for the OS or graphics drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.